# Calling nested functions

Tags: javascript, function, react-native

I'm trying to do a search bar in a flatlist in React Native.
I have a functional component, inside that I have another function `_searchFilter`, that handles filtering the data to be displayed on the flatlist, but my SearchBar conponent is at a stacknavigator header in my navigationOptions e.g.

```
function VoltAQUI (props) {
  const { markers, fetchMarkers } = props

  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMarkers({
      location: 'Av.+Paulista,+171',
      distance: 1
    })
    console.log('fetching')
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (markers.length === 0) {
      setLoading(true)
    } else {
      setData(markers)
      setLoading(false)
      console.log('fetched')
    }
  }, [markers.length])

  this._searchFilter = text => {
    const newData = markers.filter(item => {
      const itemData = `${item.name.title.toUpperCase()}`
      const textData = text.toUpperCase()
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1
    })
    setData(newData)
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <ListContainer>
        {loading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <ListMapItem
                handleClick={() => { console.log() }}
                title={item.name}
                address={item.address}
                cashback={item.cashback}
              />
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          />
        )}
      </ListContainer>
    </Container>
  )
}

VoltAQUI.navigationOptions = () => ({
  headerRight:
  <SearchBarHeader
    placeholder='Exemplo: Avenida Paulista 171'
    onChangeText={text => VoltAQUI()._searchFilter(text)}
  />
})

VoltAQUI.propTypes = {
  markers: PropTypes.array,
  fetchMarkers: PropTypes.func
}

VoltAQUI.defaultProps = {
  markers: []
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  markers: state.voltaQui.markers
})
const mapDispatchToProps = { fetchMarkers }

const addReduxProps = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)

export default addReduxProps(VoltAQUI)
```

This returns me and error: `props is undefined`.
How do I call the `_searchFilter` function on my `onChangeText` prop in `navigationOptions`?

Comment: You need to pass props into the VoltAQUI function call on the line `onChangeText={text => VoltAQUI()._searchFilter(text)}`. Try `onChangeText={text => VoltAQUI(this.props)._searchFilter(text)}`.

Comment: `VoltAQUI(this.props)` didnt work. I just edited my post to show more of the code, i using redux with mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps, does it change anything?